# How to avoid redundant data fetching in Next.js getStaticProps to improve performance

Tags: next.js, dynamic, request

the next-js server would receive repetitive data in getStaticProps

I am working on a Next.js project with the following file structure:

```
-----pages
    -----products
         -----[product_id].jsx
    -----_app.jsx
```

Inside the `[product_id].jsx` file, I have a function that retrieves the `best selling products` from the backend. However, I've noticed that the Next.js server fetches the 'best selling products' for each of the 1000 products on my site, even though the data is the same for all products.

Is there a way to optimize this so that the Next.js server fetches the 'best selling products' only once instead of making redundant requests for each product?